# How to Implement Interface Functions in User Control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Hi I'm creating test application that has a user control with a Button that will be reference in a Form.

[image]

Is it possible to bind interface

```
 public interface ICRUD
    {
        void Test();
    }
```

to the user Control button1 click event

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //CALL ICRUD.Test() execute when click on form1 and then show I am Clicked
    }
}
```

so that
i just need to implement only the interface functions to my form1.

Form1:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace TEST
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form , ICRUD
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Test()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I am Clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Regards.

Comment: How many times do you plan to delete and reask the same question?

Comment: You can have property in the user control of type ICRUD, and set this property from the form.

Comment: @M.Babcock thanks for the FAQ.This is my final question sir. and i attached sample image to make my question much cleaner.. :)

Comment: Please, in future, [edit].  You don't have lots of rep, and the system autoblocks accounts with low rep and lots of deleted questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seems right to me. It's probably not the `Form` that should be implementing this interface. What's more, the interface doesn't bring anything here.

But if you really want to do that, you can access [the `ParentForm` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform.aspx), cast it to your interface and then call the method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var crud = (ICrud)ParentForm;
    crud.Test();
}
```

Also, the convention in .Net is to write abbreviations (at least the long ones) the same as other words, so you should name your interface `ICrud`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    for(var parent = this.Parent; parent != null; parent = parent.Parent)
    {
      var crud = parent as ICRUD;
      if (crud != null)
      {
        crud.Test();
        break;
      }
    } 
}
```